# Offline tile services for MapWinGis

Tags: c#, dictionary, offline

[MapWinGIS](http://mapwingis.codeplex.com) has a function for [PrefetchToFolder](http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/class_tiles.html#a59f57c8df794993ab30af7028d72b317) which can Caches tiles to the specified file system folder for further offline use. This function works perfectly, But how can I load that tiles for creating offline map in a restricted area?
Here is a sample of using PrefetchToFolder :

```
        double y = 39;    // latitude, deg.
        double x = 140;     // longitude, deg.
        double span = 5;  // deg.
        Extents ext = new Extents();
        ext.SetBounds(x - span, y - span, 0.0, x + span, y + span, 0.0);
        axMap1.Tiles.PrefetchToFolder(ext, 8, 0, @"c:\map1", ".png", StopFunction());
```

My programming language is C#.

Here is some code which can fetch but can't load :

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TileProviders providers = axMap1.Tiles.Providers; ;
        int providerId = (int)tkTileProvider.ProviderCustom + 1;    
        providers.Add(providerId, "MyProvider", @"file:///C|/map1/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png", tkTileProjection.SphericalMercator, 1, 18);

        axMap1.Projection = tkMapProjection.PROJECTION_GOOGLE_MERCATOR;
        axMap1.TileProvider = tkTileProvider.ProviderCustom;
        axMap1.Tiles.ProviderId = providerId;

        axMap1.Latitude = 39;
        axMap1.Longitude = 140;
        axMap1.CurrentZoom = 8;

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double y = 39;    // latitude, deg.
        double x = 140;     // longitude, deg.
        double span = 5;  // deg.
        Extents ext = new Extents();
        ext.SetBounds(x - span, y - span, 0.0, x + span, y + span, 0.0);
       axMap1.Tiles.PrefetchToFolder(ext,1 , 0, @"c:\map1", ".png", StopFunction());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use server for this. forexample :  **mapserver**

for windows :

1) download ms4w : http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/index.phtml?page=downloads.html

2) extract the root directory (c:/ms4w)

3)Start your MS4W Apache Web Server by running /ms4w/apache-install.bat (at the command line or by double-clicking it). This file installs Apache as a Windows service (called "Apache Web Server") so that it starts whenever your machine is restarted. When executed, a DOS window should pop up with the following message:

```
Installing the Apache MS4W Web Server service
The Apache MS4W Web Server service is successfully installed.
Testing httpd.conf....
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service
can be started.
The Apache MS4W Web Server service is starting.
The Apache MS4W Web Server service was started successfully.
```

4)copy tile files /ms4w/Apache/htdocs/maps

5) Then you should see this files in the http://localhost/maps

**tiles file genaration** :

For this process I use mapertive. This program free and generate openstreet map. this is the link : http://maperitive.net/

Code Example :

```
    TileProviders providers = axMap1.Tiles.Providers; ;
    int providerId = (int)tkTileProvider.ProviderCustom + 1;    
    providers.Add(providerId, "MyProvider", "http:/localhost/maps/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png", tkTileProjection.SphericalMercator, 1, 18);

    axMap1.Tiles.ProviderId = providerId;
    axMap1.CurrentZoom = 8;
```

result =

[image]

Comment: Thanks Melih, As you told, I installed ms4w and that worked perfectly. Also I cached tiles with Maperitive. But there is no any view of map. http://localhost/maps/1/1/1.png shows an image, but localhost/maps/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png doesn't show any map! Do you test your solution?

Comment: Yes this solution works.  Please check the return value of providers add method if the value is false change the +1 value and try again or try to change projection to wsg84.  maybe map is added but you didnt see because of  your zoom level so add the map.zoomToTileLevel(1) line in your code instead of currentzoom

Comment: because of can't type here as comment too much, I post an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Yes this solution works. Please check the return value of providers add method if the value is false change the +1 value and try again or try to change projection to wsg84. maybe map is added but you didnt see because of your zoom level so add the map.zoomToTileLevel(1) line in your code instead of currentzoom

Tanks Melih, As you told, I checked every things (except wsg84, which I don't know anything about that) but still can't see map! Here is my code :

```
        axMap1.CtlbackColor = Color.Transparent;
        TileProviders providers = axMap1.Tiles.Providers;
        int providerId = (int)tkTileProvider.ProviderCustom + 100;
        //providers.Add(providerId, "Custom TMS provider", "http://{switch:a,b,c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png", tkTileProjection.SphericalMercator, 1, 18);
        providers.Add(providerId, "CustomTMSprovider", @"http://localhost/maps/Tiles/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png", tkTileProjection.SphericalMercator, 1, 18);
        axMap1.Tiles.ProviderId = providerId;
        axMap1.Projection = tkMapProjection.PROJECTION_WGS84;
        axMap1.GrabProjectionFromData = true;
        axMap1.ZoomBehavior = tkZoomBehavior.zbUseTileLevels;
        axMap1.ZoomToTileLevel(2);
```

If  I change the provider everything works perfectly but this provider can't load map.
As I told, [tile local server](http://localhost/maps/1/1/1.png) works good. 
Thanks again for your effort.

[image: My output]

Comment: delete the line axMap1.GeoProjection.SetWgs84();
 and change the projection axMap1.Projection = tkMapProjection.PROJECTION_WGS84 

If you change the any extents of map please remove them and try again.I added image and code.

Comment: @melih-altıntaş, we have same code, but different results. I disabled my firewall and recreate tiles with Maperitive for zoom 1 and 2.but as you can see in my last post, there is no answer! Here is my email : bsflasher (ats) gmail.com. Can you send me your tiles and code? Or send me your mail address to send you my code and tiles.

Comment: My environment is: VS 2015 (Project in .net 4 client profile), Windows 10 x86, Eset firewall, using ms4w (3.0.6) , MapWinGIS-only-v4.9.3.5-Win32.

Answer (score 0):

change your URL http:/localhost/... as http://localhost/...
you missed a '/'

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this process and I can not load the map, i have the tiles in map.mbtiles from maperitive but how i can show it: i have to export my file .mbtiles to .png? as..

> "http://localhost/maps/Tiles/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png"